# IE9 wont loads only some part of css

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, meta

There seems to be a problem with X-UA-Comptaible meta tags. Cant get them right.
Heres the site http://www.lavii.ee/academushostel and here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKfg9.jpg) of IE9

From browserstack i get this in my console: HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=Edge') ignored because document mode is already finalized. academushostel

So far googling has not helped, have tried replacing meta tag with  but no luck yet...